# Deformation and Adhesion with Particle Contact Time During Impact

Tags: classical-mechanics, adhesion, contact-mechanics

Let's say I have a spherical particle impacting a large flat target (let's say it's a half space) at high velocity. It seems I can approximate contact  time during impact by dividing impact velocity with diameter of the particle but I'm assuming if the particle and substrate have some attractive forces, let's say at the nanoscale, I'd predict the contact time to be even longer but I don't know how to calculate that. I want to factor in plastic deformation as well. I'd be satisfied with the name of a good textbook that covers this type of information if someone knows of any. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> It seems I can approximate contact time during impact by dividing
> impact velocity with diameter of the particle [...]

I'm not sure where you're getting that from: the units of measurement of:

$$\frac{v}{D}$$

is $\mathrm{1/s}$, so it's not a time, it's an *inverse time*.

Calculating the contact time is a very, very difficult thing to do. It involves making numerous assumptions and calculating highly non-linear deformations, as the sphere slows down. In essence kinetic energy is converted into elastic energy and then the reverse again.

Soft spheres (e.g. 'Softballs') will take more contact time than say, steel marbles.

But this is more the realm of *measurement* than theoretical calculation.